# How to get Smartcard reader information in java applet?

Tags: java, terminal, applet, smartcard

I'm developing a java applet that read smart card information. I can get a list of card readers using the following code:

```
TerminalFactory factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
List<CardTerminal> terminals = factory.terminals().list();
```

But all I got are the names of the terminals. Is there a way I can get the type of the terminals? eg. Contact or Contactless?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use of IAIK wrapper for access to smart card.

get more information from [IAIK](http://jce.iaik.tugraz.at/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I'm not really looking for something to access the smart card information. I'm trying to get the information from the reader. So far I can only tell if a reader is contact or contactless by its name. I'm asking if there's a better way. Do you know about that?